# Installation step failed-Debian 8.6.0 net install in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, debian, installation, virtual-machine

It seems that other people have seen this error before but I cannot find this exact problem elsewhere on superuser.

I have a Virtual Box VM using 2GB RAM, 20GB VDI, Encrypted LVM and Debian 8.6.0 netinst image.
When its installing software (whether on OSX or WIndows host) I finally get "Installation step failed" and have to restart the softare install portion of the OS install. ... But to no avail. I get the same error again!

Any ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a very casual Linux user, so I don't have the knowledge or experience to give a concrete answer. However, I did have this same issue in the last two days. I got around it and it seems to be running fine now.

What I did:

- Go back to the `"Detect Disks"` step
- Go up and select `"Guided partition"` again, ignoring the configuration stuff from the previous attempt(s). I wanted to overwrite the partitions because you'll get errors if there are some leftover files from the previous attempt. [IMG: Select "Guided Partition"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrHTk.png)
- Proceed until you get to the "Partition method" step
- Select `"Guided - use entire disk"` (Note: I previously used the un-encrypted LVM option and got the error, so now we're avoiding that) [IMG: Partitioning method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Vay.png)
- Proceed until you reach the "Partitioning *scheme*:" setting
- Select "All files in one partition" (Note: I previously used the separate /home, /var, and /tmp option and got the error)
- Proceed as usual...

I would have to think maybe there's an issue with LVM in the setup process, but again, I don't know for sure. I wouldn't think the partitioning scheme (separate /home /var and /tmp) would mess things up...

Since we're both using VMs, we might as well set up a few more and try a couple different routes.

I hope this helps!

---

My hardware/software setup when attempting this install:

- VM:

  - debian-live-8.6.0-i386-gnome-desktop.iso
  - VirtualBox 5.1.10r112026 (Qt5.6.2)
  - 8GB VDI
  - 4096 MB base memory
  - 2 processors
  - 64MB video memory (no gfx card on host hardware, just the integrated gfx)
- Host:

  - Host Processor: i7-4790k
  - Host Memory: 12GB
  - Host OS: Windows 7

Comment: That worked. I'm dismayed that I can't use separate partitions though... ah well its just a VM. Thanks!

Comment: @Chrips Great! I'm glad it helped! Cheers, man!

Comment: A year later, debian 9.3, VirtualBox 5.2.2 - same problem. Solution works, though

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem while trying to create a debian VM (using debian-live-8.6.0-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso) on top of VirtualBox VM.

@darkscrap solution does work, although it seems that the only variable that matters is selecting **All files in one partition /**, for some reason **choosing separate partitions for /var, /tmp et /home generates the "Installation step failed" error** on virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

My issue may have been similar to yours.

Installing from Debian Live 10.3 (Buster) to a Virtualbox disk. Guest only had 512 mb ram, so installer is in low memory mode, not sure if it matters.

Failed at software install. Looking at the logs on console 4 (Alt+F4) showed module loop not found.

By using the console on 3 (Alt+F3), tried both udpkg and Anna-install the loop-modules udeb found in /cdrom (find /cdrom/ | grep -i loop). Then tried the software install step in the text installer again (Alt+F1). This worked. It loaded the module needed for the installer to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was hanging up on the graphical install when trying to install Debian 10.9.0 in a VirtualBox.  When I used the text mode install, the operation went flawlessly.